# Simplified process for Conditional Bin Packing in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bin-packing

I have a algorithm which does bin packing based on certain conditions. I find that the flow of the algorithm is little bit complex for the readers to understand.

Below you can find the developed Java code. Is there a much simplified alternative flow for this code?

```
void binpack() {
boolean set=false, cmap=false;
        while(set==false) {
            set=true;
            cmap=false;
            pack[k.cnt]=new bins(k.lim, k.ptim);
            for(int i=0;i<tot;i++) {           
                int s1,s2;
                if(jm[i][1]==0) {
                    s1=jm[i][0]; 
                    set=false;

                    else if(pack[k.cnt].pushk<k.lim) {
                        for(int j=0;j<pack[k.cnt].pushk;j++) {
                            s2=pack[k.cnt].binjm[j][0];
                            for (Iterator<Integer> g= list[s1].iterator(); g.hasNext();) {

    }
}
```

Notes:

ptim-->present time

etim-->end time

lim-->limit

Comment: Where does the `k` and `j` values come in? If those are class variables, they're incredibly poorly named...

Comment: I know this is a somewhat subjective issue, but i think you should put the opening braces on the end of the line instead of putting them on their own line. All i see when i look at that is { { { { { { { { { {. On that note, you should extract some methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things off the top of my head:

1. Variable names should be more expressive. Don't abbreviate, especially not to save one or two characters (e.g. `ptim`, `chk()`)
2. Put spaces after opening and before closing parentheses, after and before operators and so on. It sounds daft but you'll be amazed how easier your code will be to read.
3. Avoid unnecessary boolean comparisons (e.g. `if ( bool == false )` should be `if ( !bool )`
4. Avoid one-liner `if`s or `while`s, use proper `{}` blocks.
5. Don't pre-declare variables if you don't have to.
6. Instead of the double break structure you have in your nested loop,  `break` to a label.
7. And most of all: factor some of those loops out into methods.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: Do not abbreviate variables just to save some typing. This leads to obfuscate incrompreensible codes like that one.

Second, have you already heard about java.util.Map?